# Yii CGridView search filter with array as data provider

Tags: php, arrays, gridview, yii

I'm pretty new to Yii ( and frameworks all together ) and I'm trying to show the search results, that are contained inside an array, with GridView like this:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => $model['res_id']
    , 'dataProvider' => new CArrayDataProvider( $model['company'] )
    , 'ajaxUpdate' => true
    , 'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-bordered table-striped table-hover'
    , 'pagerCssClass' => 'cni_pagination'
    , 'pager' => array(
            'htmlOptions' => array( 'class' => 'pagination' )
            , 'header' => ''
        )
));
?>
```

The results are show just fine:

[image]

But I'm struggling how to add the Search filter to this table.

All I could find is to add `$model->search` to it, but, since my `$model` is generated from an array, I can't use that.

Any suggestions how to do this? Do I need to create additional class, that will define this? A link to the correct manual will also help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/232/using-filters-with-cgridview-and-carraydataprovider/) useful link and got it done.

It's easier then I though :)